# Installing Multiple App APK in Android

Tags: android

My application suite is composed of multiple APKs corresponding to different applications. Installation of the different APKs should done in parallel so that to avoid user having older version for some app and newer version for other apps.
In the current approach, the user has to install each of the APK explicitly. If one of the APP is not updated with newer version, then it becomes an issue.

Is there a way to install multiple APKs corresponding to different App in one go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer depends on what you want to achieve here.
If you want a single app to be able to install other apps without asking the user for his opinion, the answer clearly is no, and for good reasons:

1. The apps automatically installed would not be able to display their required permissions, which is a rule from Google Play in principle.
2. This behavior could be dangerous as it would then be easy for someone to produce for instance a game app and add a malware to it that would automatically install as well and sneak into the devices of whoever would use the app.

But there is an alternative to it, requiring the intermediate of a computer.
The project Mass APK Installer Tool was designed for exactly this purpose.
Check this article [about Mass APK Installer Tool](http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-uninstall-multiple-apps-android/). The link to the code is broken as it has moved to its new location, [here](http://code.fosshub.com/mass-apk-installer).